# Scheme list modification

Tags: regex, list, scheme

I am trying to write a scheme function that takes a list of the form:

```
((#f ((1 1) (2 1)))
 (#f ((1 3) (5 1)))
 (#f ((1 4) (7 1)))
)
```

and removes all the #f to give a list like:

```
( ((1 1) (2 1))
  ((1 3) (5 1))
  ((1 4) (7 1))
)
```

I have tried the following code but cannot get it to work:

```
(define meth
  (lambda lst
    (if (equal? (cdr lst) '())
      (cdr (car lst))
      (cons (list-ref (car lst) 1) (meth (cdr lst))))))
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `map` to apply the `cdr` function to each sublist in the list, like this: `(map cdr lst)`. However this will give you

```
( (((1 1) (2 1)))
  (((1 3) (5 1)))
  (((1 4) (7 1)))
)
```

for your sample input, which is one level of nesting more than your sample output. So to get your sample output, use `list-ref` to get the second element of each sublist:

```
(define (meth lst) (map (lambda (x) (list-ref x 1)) lst))
```

Edit: As Eli Barzilay helpfully pointed out, there is the `cadr` function to get the second element of a list, so this can be shortened to:

```
(define (meth lst) (map cadr lst))
```

Comment: Note that `cadr` returns the second element.  (Also, this is a fine answer -- but the "modification" in the question text is bogus.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it more closely to what you had:

```
(define meth
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) '())
      ((cons (cadr (car lst)) (meth (cdr lst))))
      )
    )
  )


(define a '(
            (#f ((1 1) (2 1)))
            (#f ((1 3) (5 1)))
            (#f ((1 4) (7 1)))
            ))
```